# TODO comment of pycharm on Mac doesn't show sharp color like in Linux

Tags: pycharm

When I go to **preference** --> **Editor** --> **Inspections** --> **TODO comment**.
And I select the **Severity** of the yellow colour for the warning.
Does anyone have the same problem then? If so, I would appreciate a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how the `TODO`'s are matched at `Settings > Editor > TODO`. The default regex'es match a case insenstive `todo` word (e.g. `ToDo` will still be matched).

If by chance you want a dash in the `todo` (i.e. `to-do`), you can modify the existing pattern `\btodo\b.*` to `\bto-?do\b.*`.

[image: todo-matching]

Comment: Thanks, but actually my question is it doesn't detect the todo comment

Comment: Edited my answer.